# content gets scrambled

Tags: content, wysiwyg, text

Every time someone edits our blog the content is displaying all wrong.

It looks perfect in the wysiwyg editor but when you publish the page the content is completely wrong (pictures displayed next to each other etc.

How to prevent this?

[example link](http://dierenasieltienen.com/nieuw/?page_id=32)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the images are defined as floating to the left.

To solve this, you can add a `clear: both` to the `<h4>` elements (it probably won't hurt to do this in the stylesheet - will there be a situation where you need a title that exists next to a float?).

Comment: Indeed that will never happen. I will try this right away